# Call Sub Procedure using Gridview Column Imagefield

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a Gridview column called "Path" and when the user clicks on it I want it to pass that value of the "Path" cell to a sub procedure to execute the following code,

```
process.start(Path)
```

Currently the table is filled via SQL query and the "Path" is clickable but it wants to take me to URL which won't work for my situation. I also tried the Hyperlink column as well but was having the same problem. Any guidance would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a LinkButton instead of a HyperLink.

Set the CommandArgument on the LinkButton, you could use either the GridView.RowCommand event handler or a LinkButton.OnClick event handler to call your sub.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="gridView_RowCommand">
   <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Path">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbPath" runat="server" CommandArgument="<%# Eval("Path")%>" OnClick="lbPath_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then in code behind:

```
Protected Sub lbPath_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim linkButton As LinkButton = CType(sender, LinkButton)
    Process.Start(linkButton.CommandArgument)
End Sub
```

For reference

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am new to GridViews but basically I had to convert all my columns to TemplateFields and used what you had. Can you explain what the "Eval" means in your commandarguement?